# Is there a feature or extension in Azure DevOps Pipeline that enables direct navigation to a YAML template through clicking?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am looking for some tool/extension that will let me navigate to yaml template by clicking on its reference in another yaml file.
I found this Chrome extension but it's not always work: [YMLink](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/ymlink/fohlplgphadlhkaaamjfiipedeagaheb)

I tried the above extension, also searched in Azure Devops extensions but found nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a feature or extension in Azure DevOps Pipeline that enables direct navigation to a YAML template through clicking?

Yes. I suggest that you can use the Built-in feature(**View template** option) in YAML Pipeline.

When you use the YAML template in Pipeline, it will show an option: **View template**.

[image]

When you click this option, it will show the content of the template file.

For example:

[image]

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [View and edit templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/yaml-pipeline-editor?view=azure-devops#view-and-edit-templates)